# IE not saving asp.net authentication token / cookies

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, authentication, cookies

I have an asp.net site. Its a mixture of web forms and MVC2.

I have this on 2 different servers which I get to via different urls.

On one server authentication works fine via all browsers (IE 8, FF 3.6, Chrome)

On the other IE 8 fails, it doesn't send back the cookie on the request to the page after authenticating.

Using Fiddler I have seen that both sites attempt to set the cookie, in the response from the login page.

Response Header I see from both servers
Set-Cookie: DemandLaunch=CCA4...E79C2D1; path=/; HttpOnly

Both sites are in the internet zone of IE.

I'm at a loose for what to check now.

I also have a page that sets a cookie via c# code and that cookie fails in IE as well.

The IE issue is not on a single computer either.  I see this failure on 4 different computers Internet Explorer.

**My urls which I should have included were:**

beta.[site].com - works

beta_[company].[site].com - fails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the name of the server. It shouldn't have an Underscore in its name.

If that doesn't help, you should try these out...

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rahulso/troubleshooting-cookies-a-case-study)

http://aspalliance.com/1182

Comment: The underscore was exactly my problem.

Comment: Same issue verified here. Our environment is: .Net 4.0, IIS 7. Only problematic in IE8. We tried both Inproc and SqlServer Sessionstate modes unsuccessfully. Removing the underscore did the trick.

Comment: IE11 does accept a domain but it does not accept domains of localhost or machine names without a TLD like `http://myservername/`. It also apparently chokes on subdomains with underscores. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690114/internet-explorer-11-wont-set-cookies-on-a-site)