# Internet Explorer 11 won't set cookies on a site

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-11

For some reason IE11 (only IE11, tested with other IE9 and IE10) won't create a session on a site i've been working on. So this means that a basic functionality such as site login won't work.

On other browsers this is working perfectly.

I researched a bit and found out that IE won't work with domains with underscore.. but my domain doesn't have one so what could be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a resolve? I am experiencing the same problem with a member who's IE11 on Win 8 refuses to accept the session cookie,

Comment: I haven't found a solution..

Comment: I've added the domain to trusted sites, I've forced acceptance of cookies through the security settings, I've reset the browser, deleted all data, but still IE11 refuses to accept the session cookie. Google Chrome works fine as does FireFox, but IE won't budge.

Comment: I too am having this problem, already 2 users stating they can't login to my site. Whats going one, I think there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: Did we find an answer to this problem? I have the same problem. Tried removing domain attribute and no difference.

Comment: Underscore is not an allowed domain name character according to RFC1035. As such, the hint you've found that IE is not working with one is ... bizarre.

Answer (score 38):

IE 11 does not like a domain value in the cookie. Leave it empty.

Wrong for IE 11:

```
Set-Cookie: kohanasession=foobar; expires=Tue, 09-Apr-2016 01:01:01 GMT; path=/; domain=tc.mk; httponly
```

Correct for IE 11:

```
Set-Cookie: kohanasession=foobar; expires=Tue, 09-Apr-2016 01:01:01 GMT; path=/; httponly
```

Comment: @freeworlder can you be more specific? Maybe you have multiple errors in your cookie setting code.

Comment: Hi @bebbo, do you have a reference to verify your claim?

Comment: @Matt: it solved the problem in the project I was working.

Comment: @bebbo After searching a lot I found this answer and finally this solution worked. Thank you man!

Comment: More info: IE11 *does* accept a domain but it does *not* accept domains of `localhost` or machine names without a TLD like `http://myservername/`. It also apparently chokes on subdomains with underscores. See: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Apr/25/Internet-Explorer-and-Cookie-Domains

Comment: I was struggling to figure out the issue with angular code. Your suggestion helped me resolve this issue thanks

Comment: Thanks @leiavoia! That's it! This had me while debugging an issue on localhost. Adding `127.0.0.1 home.local` to `/etc/hosts` and using that domain instead, fixed my issues.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but hopefully this helps someone in the future.
You cannot have a blank `expires=;` value in a cookie in IE11.  You just have to leave the `expires` field out altogether.

Answer (score 7):

This may only apply to another-domain cookies, but if someone finds this via Google (like I did) this may help.

IE11 may not set cookies depending on its Privacy settings.

This worked for me:

[image]

(Internet Options -> Privacy -> Advanced -> enable all cookie cases there)

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue because I was running a single-page Vue application. I was setting the cookie in one route, then immediately routing to a different "page". However, it seems like **IE won't send cookies until next page load**. So instead of using pushState, I had to force the browser to re-load the page.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this problem myself. In my case, the problem was caused by executing the "ClearAuthenticationCache" command upon successful login. The command was executed to remove HTTP authentication, but it turns out that it will remove session cookies as well.

So I would recommend removing the "ClearAuthenticationCache" call if you executing it after a login.

```
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");
```

For more information, please see the following link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/04/04/understanding-session-lifetime/

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue with a different setup, I'd like to share what the problem was and how I resolved it. Hoping it would provide ideas to solutions for those who suffer.

**The Setup**

1. Authentication service who sets auth cookies sitting on **some-domain.com**
2. React application bundled and ran by Webpack Server on **localhost**
3. Requests go through Webpack proxy to land on **some-domain.com**. For example

```
  '/api/': {
    target: 'some-domain.com',
    logLevel: 'debug',
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
    '^/api': '/api'
    }
  }
```

**The Problem #1**

Because my authentication service sets cookies on **some-domain.com**, and my React App was running on **localhost**, it doesn't have that cookie attached to its requests, and my authentication flow failed.

**Solution**

I had to rewrite the cookie domain, so I added this line to the proxy config on webpack

```
    cookieDomainRewrite: {
      '.some-domain.com': 'localhost'
    }
```

it looks like this in webpack.config.js

```
  devServer: {
    ...
    proxy: {
      '/api/': {
        target: 'some-domain.com',
        logLevel: 'debug',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api': '/api'
        },
        cookieDomainRewrite: {
          '.some-domain.com': 'localhost'
        }
      }
    }
    ...
  }
```

So this was fine on chrome, firefox... but broken in IE 11.

because IE 11 doesn't support the domain **localhost** for reasons mentioned in previous posts in this thread, when the rewrite happens, cookie is lost.

The final change I had to make was

```
   cookieDomainRewrite: {
      '.some-domain.com': null
    }
```

This will make the domain defaults to localhost while keeping it valid for IE 11.

**Sum Up**

when working with cookies and IE make sure:

1. your client and server's domain match
2. use null for domain value if working with localhost

Answer (score 1):

In order for the cookie persistence functionality to work as expected in IE11 I found that I had to use the toGMTString() method (I tried both toGMTString() and toUTCString()) for the **expires** field when creating the cookie.  Before adding this, the cookie would not persist after the browser was closed.

Example:

```
var expiryDate = new Date();
expiryDate.setTime(expiryDate.getTime() + (3650 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
document.cookie = 'name=value' + '; expires=' + expiryDate.toGMTString() + ';path=/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the cookies your server is sending down the date of expiry seems to be yesterday. Is the date time set correctly on your server?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting one of the session cookies twice:

    `Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3iv5l4tn2ugkbf4vt09lilsi06; path=/
    Set-Cookie: identity=1468380643; expires=Mon, 09-Jan-2017 12:31:46 GMT; path=/; domain=.tc.mk; httponly
    Set-Cookie: kohanasession=u5rrhtaj731h3p9s44jhp0k612; expires=Tue, 09-Feb-2016 12:31:46 GMT; path=/; domain=tc.mk; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: kohanasession=u5rrhtaj731h3p9s44jhp0k612; expires=Tue, 09-Feb-2016 12:31:46 GMT; path=/; domain=tc.mk; httponly`

Internet explorer doesnt resend this cookie info on successive calls, while eg Chrome will just take one of the 'kohanasession'. Try sending the 'kohanasession' only once.

Also the domain you're setting in the cookie is 'tc.mk', while you have a SEO redirect to www.tc.mk. I think IE will not use the cookie for www in this case. Try configuring it to www.tc.mk

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Beeby suggested, please check expiration of your cookie & set date time correctly on your server.

I have checked session for your site & in even chrome it's seems to be expired.

[image]

Seems some issue with cookie creation/expiration date & IE behaves different than chrome based browsers. Different cookies have different times than others.

Answer (score 0):

I searched high and low but couldn't find a solution for my issue. After debugging i realized that IE (unlike the other browsers) need the PATH part to *start* with '/'. I had mine line 'subdir/' and had to prepend it to be '/subdir/' to satisfy IE.