# Web app doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: session, cookies, internet-explorer-11

My application works beautifully on Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera, but fails on Internet Explorer 11 (I haven't tried earlier versions yet). Basically, I find that I cannot log in. I have narrowed the problem down to an issue with cookies. On login attempt, I get through to the server fine, and the response is the exact same as with any other browser. But for whatever reason, even though the `Set-Cookie` header is set, the cookie is not saved and sent on the next request to the server. My application has a (mostly) RESTful backend, and so authenticates on most requests. This obviously fails because the cookie is not set!

This problem persists whether served from localhost or from a real server. I should mention that it **is** a cross origin request, but the proper headers are in place (and they work on other browsers)

The response headers (when served from localhost) are as follows:

```
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    accept, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    POST, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://localhost:8000
Cache-Control   no-cache,no-store
Content-Length  68
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Thu, 05 Mar 2015 20:00:20 GMT
Frame-Ancestors none
Server  waitress
Set-Cookie  session-id=ZqANyJ4KRUFoOaVgtGs/hcX+fxjMcCVM0kdRqF4riHglfAeBJJK56X9wn0XsNdPwUg; Domain=; HttpOnly;
Strict-Transport-Security   max-age=31536000;
X-Frame-Options deny
```

I cannot figure out why this doesn't work solely in IE11! The app is not in an `iframe`, and the cookie actually appears in the cookies tab in the IE developer tools when I click on the network request, but it is not subsequently sent along with the next ones.

Some of my attempted solutions were:

- Adding the `Cache-Control` header
- Removing the `HttpOnly` flag from the cookie
- Adding the `Domain` flag to the cookie (set as `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`)
- Removing Headers like `X-Frame-Options`, `Frame-Ancestors`, and `Strict-Transport-Security`
- Tried multiple computers
- Changed security settings to accept all cookies

All failed. Ideas?

Comment: Just a dumb thought: could it be an IE11 browser setting that is preventing the saving of the cookie?

Comment: I have tried on multiple computers, to make sure it wasnt a config problem, and i also changed security settings to accept all cookies. No dice.

Comment: Have you every found the solution Tom? I'm facing the exact same problem with a website. Seems it has something to do with the domain, as it doesn't work when leaving it blank, using either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: I never found out why this was happening. I was using AngularJS and ended up using a little extension for making cross origin requests and that made it work. This one is a puzzler for sure

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. If I ever fix this, I'll let you know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer 11 won't set cookies on a site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690114/internet-explorer-11-wont-set-cookies-on-a-site)