# SecurityContextHolder bearing an anonymous user despite successful login

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

First question here, I'm new to spring and Spring Security, I'm currently working on a small project which involves a simple authentication system using ReactJS and Spring Boot, I ran into an issue where upon successful log-in, the server fails to provide the currently logged-in user and defaults to anonymous user, I suspect that I unknowingly made a mistake while changing configurations on the class that implements the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` interface, since it used to work before I did those changes. Other than that I'm clueless at this point.

So a recap, registration works like a charm, login works and executes a method indicating that it was successful, but can't seem to save the session?

This is the configure method from my config class implementing the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`  interface:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().disable().csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/resources/**" , "/register")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and().formLogin()
    .failureHandler(handleFailure())
    .successHandler(handleSuccess()) 
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .cors();
}
```

and this is the code which **used** to return the values that I wanted to fetch.

```
@GetMapping(path="/userdetails")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getUserDetails(){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return createResponse(auth.getPrincipal(),HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I'd be happy to provide more code samples since I don't want to paste a lot of codes here because I'm frankly clueless in where the source of the issue is.

Edit:
This is the jquery method that I'm using for sending out the login form.

```
$.post(`${__SERVER}/login` , $("#login-form").serialize())
```

Am I misunderstanding something here? the documentations says the default endpoint for sending login forms is /login if it's unspecified.

This is the url string for registration:

```
http://localhost:8080/register?username=example@mail.com&password=asdfasdf&passwordConfirm=asdfasdf
```

and this is for login forms

```
http://localhost:8080/login?username=example@mail.com&password=asdfasdf
```

Debugging them in the server shows that they do in fact arrive and are wrapped in their respective objects quite neatly, but it just doesn't work somehow.

Screenshots:

[Response headers after a supposed successful login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wqkT.png)

[Headers after requesting for the currently authenticated user.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnQqR.png)

[Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J36W6.png)

Update:
Apparently some users had issues similar to mine when using microsoft edge:[set-cookie header not setting cookie in Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456797/set-cookie-header-not-setting-cookie-in-edge)

So I installed other browsers just to check, and unfortunately not one of them managed to work out the issue.

I decided to play with some tutorials I found online, I stumbled upon this one:https://hellokoding.com/spring-boot/security-login-mysql-jsp/

Creating a carbon copy of the repo of the tutorial, I then made incremental changes, What caught my attention(and ultimately fixed the issue) is this code

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /
```

Which is found in my application properties, I inserted it into my property file and It worked!, wth?

Can anyone explain how and why that change did the trick?

The whole model at this point seems so confusing, any clarifications will be appreciated!

Comment: Ahh, I see, I removed that before but that didn't do it,I also edited the post to provide more details about the requests that the server receives, Login works! as the server refuses a login if it's provided with invalid credentials as expected. but I can't access any authenticated endpoints for some reason. /userdetails is just there to provide confirmation if securitycontextholder is indeed remembering the session. This might be hindsight. help

Comment: I attached a few thumbnails, Hopefully those can provide an insight as to what's going on

Comment: I see no session cookie in your request. Then you are not logged in. Look at the cookie tab and check if there is a cookie with the same ID from response.

Comment: BTW: Your screenshots are from Postman not from your browser. That could be the reason for your problem. Use the browser.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I included the cookies now after a successful login(from springs default form login)

Comment: So, I should probably rephrase my question, How does authentication with spring security's form login actually work? they should be given by the server(Set-Cookie header) when a login is confirmed right? .. What's strange is that this used to work before, without any hiccups.

Comment: Yes, form login works with a HTTP session, hence you need a session cookie in every request. However, your browser automatically adds cookies.