# asp .net core app doesn't set response cookie in IE and EDGE but works well in firefox and chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a login controller with a post action which redirects to home page after successful login. I am using following code for redirection, which works well in Chrome and Firefox. but doesn't redirect in IE and EDGE, and response cookie not set

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToRoute("default", new { controller = "", action = "" });
    }
}
```

My Login action

```
public IActionResult Login(string userName, string password)
{
   try
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Username/Password can not be empty");

            var session = CreateSession(userName, password);
            var returnUrl = Request.Query["returnUrl"];
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Login", ex.Message);
    }

        return View();
    }
```

I am using my own session management for which I set session cookies like following

```
CookieOptions option = new CookieOptions();
option.Path = AppPath;
option.Domain = AppHost;             
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(AppSessionToken, "SomeSessionId", option);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching a lot for exact answer, I found that Internet Explorer (all versions) doesn't allow you to specify a domain of localhost, a local IP address or machine name. When you do, Internet Explorer simply ignores the cookie. 
So I removed following line

```
option.Domain = AppHost;
```

from my codes and everything start working as expected on both IE and EDGE.

Comment: Was [Internet Explorer 11 won't set cookies on a site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22690114/1115360) one of the resources that helped?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post your route mapping from `Startup.cs`, I am not sure why it didn't work for you. Maybe you shouldn't override the `controller` and `action` parameter by passing `new { controller = "", action = "" }` into the `RedirectToRoute()` method?

Instead, have you tried just calling the method with the route name, like

```
return RedirectToRoute("default");
```

#### Or, you can use `RedirectToAction()`

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
{
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}

// action, controller and route values
return RedirectToAction("index", "home", new { area = "" });
```